# Having problems scripting SVGs

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm having some trouble with manipulating SVGs through javascript. I'd like to increase the length of a line through clicking a button. I've included this code in the head tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
x=135;
y=135;
var container = document.getElementById("svgbox");
var mySvg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");


function svg() {
mySvg.setAttribute("version", "1.2");
mySvg.setAttribute("baseProfile", "tiny");
mySvg.setAttribute("height","300px");
mySvg.setAttribute("width","300px");
container.appendChild(mySvg);
}

function line() {
x=x-10;
y=y-10;
var L1 = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "line");
    L1.setAttribute("x1", "100"); L1.setAttribute("y1", "100");
    L1.setAttribute("x2", x); L1.setAttribute("y2", y);
    L1.setAttribute("stroke", "#05adc7");
    L1.setAttribute("stroke-width", "2px");
    mySvg.appendChild(L1);
}
</script>
```

This is the body text:

```
<body onload="svg()">
<form>
<input type="button" onClick="line()" />
</form>
<div id="svgbox">
</div>
</body>
```

But when I click on the button, I get an error telling me that the variable "container" is null. Does anyone know what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works if you put the line `var container = document.getElementById("svgbox");` in the svg function.

```
function svg() {
var container = document.getElementById("svgbox");
mySvg.setAttribute("version", "1.2");
mySvg.setAttribute("baseProfile", "tiny");
mySvg.setAttribute("height","300px");
mySvg.setAttribute("width","300px");
container.appendChild(mySvg);
}
```

The reason container is `null` in your code is because the DOM has not loaded yet when the line `var container = document.getElementById("svgbox");` gets executed.

You need to declare container after either the `DOMContentLoaded` event or `window.onload` event is fired.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common gotcha in DOM scripting, for both SVG and HTML. The problem is that the svgbox element is not yet loaded when the JavaScript executes. The easiest solution is to simply move your script tag so that it is the last element in the document. This is a bit ugly, though, so most JavaScript libraries include a method that accepts a callback to execute after the document has been loaded. For example, if you were using jQuery, then your script tag would look like the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    x=135;
    y=135;
    var container = document.getElementById("svgbox");
    var mySvg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");


    svg = function() {
    mySvg.setAttribute("version", "1.2");
    mySvg.setAttribute("baseProfile", "tiny");
    mySvg.setAttribute("height","300px");
    mySvg.setAttribute("width","300px");
    container.appendChild(mySvg);
    }

    line = function() {
    x=x-10;
    y=y-10;
    var L1 = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "line");
    L1.setAttribute("x1", "100"); L1.setAttribute("y1", "100");
    L1.setAttribute("x2", x); L1.setAttribute("y2", y);
    L1.setAttribute("stroke", "#05adc7");
    L1.setAttribute("stroke-width", "2px");
    mySvg.appendChild(L1);
    }
})
</script>
```

Comment: Turns out the easiest way was to include container inside the line function. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Another quick question.... I thought I could get around the code aesthetics and functionality problems by having the onload event fire within the head tag. But this doesn't work. Does anyone know why?

Comment: What do you mean by "have the onload event fire in the head tag"?

Comment: By the way, the above is a fairly canonical approach in DOM scripting, both for HTML and SVG. As such, most JavaScript libraries include methods to facilitate it.